# how to pass php variable value to action attribute of html form

Tags: php, html

I want to pass php variable value as a action to html form. I am trying as follows, but it is not working.

```
<?php
    $url='test.php';
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form name="upload" action="<?=$url?>" method="post" >
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

All this code are in one php file.

Comment: is it redirecting to test.php? How do you know it is not working?

also you should use a consistent form of the php tag. The long version is often preferred because it avoids confusion/problems with ASP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `<?php echo $url ?>` 
If it works, then short_open_tag in the php.ini is turned off. That means you will need to either turn it on or use the long open tag `<?php` throughout your code.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to enable [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) if your example doesn't work.

```
<?php
    ini_set('short_open_tag', 'on');
    $url='test.php';
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form name="upload" action="<?=$url?>" method="post" >
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternately, write it like this:

```
<?php
    $url='test.php';
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form name="upload" action="<?php echo $url ?>" method="post" >
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<form name="upload" action="<? echo $url ?>" method="post" >
```

Comment: Or `<form name="upload" action"<?=$url;?>" method="post">`, without the single quotes wrapping the php snippet.

Comment: If it's not working, try looking at the source output and paste that line

Answer (score 0):

Remove your single quotes:

```
<form name="upload" action="<?=$url?>" method="post">
```